# Windows IOCTL for reading raw CD-ROM data not returning error correction data

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, ioctl, cd-rom

I am attempting to make a program that extracts raw sector data from optical discs of various types, starting with CDs (data and audio).

This is nothing special, and the concept itself is fine and working on Linux with similar IOCTLs.

The problem I am having just on Windows is that the ECC/EDC data is not correct (basically zeroed out). You can see this by comparing what the command returns with other programs output like IsoBuster or ImgBurn (or using equivalent commands on Linux).

Is this data something that the Windows security policy affects for some reason? Or a driver bug?

Note that I am seeing this happen on Windows 10. I get the same result when running as administrator.

To be clear about what data is affected, see the nice table here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM#CD-ROM_format. On a normal data CD (mode 1) it is the last 288 bytes of a 2352 sector.

Code to demonstrate the issue:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>  // From the Win32 SDK \Mstools\Include
#include "ntddcdrm.h"  // From the Windows NT DDK \Ddk\Src\Storage\Inc


int main()
{

    HANDLE  hCD = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\D:", GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,
        0);

    //the sector to read
    int lba = 0;

    RAW_READ_INFO rawReadInfo;
    rawReadInfo.DiskOffset.QuadPart = (long long)lba * 2048;
    rawReadInfo.SectorCount = 1;
    rawReadInfo.TrackMode = RawWithC2AndSubCode;
    DWORD x_size;

    char* buf = (char*)malloc(CD_RAW_SECTOR_WITH_C2_AND_SUBCODE_SIZE);

    int rc = DeviceIoControl(hCD, IOCTL_CDROM_RAW_READ,
        &rawReadInfo, sizeof(rawReadInfo),
        buf, CD_RAW_SECTOR_WITH_C2_AND_SUBCODE_SIZE,
        &x_size, NULL);

    printf("rc: %d\n", rc);
    printf("x_size: %d\n", x_size);

    int i;
    printf("\nSync, Addr, Mode (16 bytes)\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%hhX", buf[i]); //this data comes back fine
    }
    printf("\nData (2048 bytes)\n");
    for (i = 16; i < 16+2048; i++) {
        printf("%hhX", buf[i]); //this data comes back fine
    }
    printf("\nED, RZ, EC (288 bytes)\n");
    for (i = 16 + 2048; i < 16 + 2048 + 288; i++) {
        printf("%hhX", buf[i]); //this data comes back wrong
    }
    printf("\nC2, Sub (392 bytes)\n");
    for (i = 16 + 2048 + 288; i < 2744; i++) {
        printf("%hhX", buf[i]); //not sure if this is right or not
    }

    //dumb code to block terminal from closing
    char str[80];
    fgets(str, 10, stdin);


    return 0;
}
```

Side by side comparison between output and IsoBuster sector view:
[image]

FYI for anyone coming here in the future, the next best thing to get this to work is definitely to use SPTI as described here: [How to issue a READ CD command to a CD-ROM drive in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884540/how-to-issue-a-read-cd-command-to-a-cd-rom-drive-in-windows). I don't want to consider that an answer to why the Windows IOCTL doesn't work though (omits the EDC)!

Comment: That variable you named `dwNotUsed`.... you need to use it.

Comment: @BenVoigt disagree, but added to appease and avoid confusion.

Comment: It would be nice to know what you are actually getting for `rc` and `x_size`.

Comment: Might also be worth trying with a page-aligned buffer, since the docs say that the buffer can be directly used in DMA.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you - added rc and screenshot of output, including comparison with IsoBuster sector view. Can you explain or link to info on using a page-aligned buffer?

Comment: Check your buffer size -- it isn't big enough to possibly contain all the information you thought you were getting.  You are reading past the end of your allocated buffer, lucky you didn't get a page fault.  Also, it looks like the header is 16 bytes not 14.

Comment: Also, there's nothing in the name or description of `CD_RAW_SECTOR_WITH_C2_AND_SUBCODE_SIZE` that suggests you would get the 288 byte block you're interested in.  You got the header, the raw sector, and the 392 bytes of C2 & Sub.

Comment: @BenVoigt the buffer is 2352+296+96 (raw sector size+C2+subcode) which is exactly what I am requesting with the IOCTL_CDROM_RAW_READ command for one sector. The data I care about, that is wrong is just the last 288 of the 2352 (not the 296 C2 +96 subcode).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169539/discussion-between-hooby3dfx-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: Do you need to use [`FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa364556 "MSDN") before performing the read?

Comment: @BrianNixon - thanks - I just tried it, but same result

Comment: Think some more about what Ben Voight pointed out. Look at your `x_size` – it’s 2456, which is 16 header + 2048 data + 296 C2 + 96 subcode. It appears you are _not_ getting the 4 ED + 8 RZ + 276 EC you are looking for.

Comment: @BrianNixon - yes that is the root of this question! I am trying to figure out why that data is not returned. (Sorry, I will try and rephrase the question to be more clear)

Comment: Ah, OK; I misunderstood. When you say the data are “not correct” you really mean they’re “not present”.
P.S. You may be leaking some personal info in your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be a little late but here it is, the short one: You cannot use the `IOCTL_CDROM_RAW_READ` control code to read mode-1 tracks in a raw way.

The long answer:
When you look at `x_size`, you see that the function did not read the amount of data you exptected it to. You expected `CD_RAW_SECTOR_WITH_C2_AND_SUBCODE_SIZE`, i.e. 2744, but you received only 2456. Another giveaway for this fact are the `0xCD` chars shown in your screenshot. Visual C initializes memory with the value `0xCD` in debug mode to facilitate debugging. So this part of the array was probably not written to at all.

So which data did you actually receive from the function call? It seems to me like you received 12 bytes of sync data, then 4 bytes of sector header (3 bytes for address, `0x00 0x02 0x00` in your case, 1 byte for mode, `0x01` in your case), then 2048 bytes of user data, then 296 bytes of C2 error information, and then 96 bytes of subcode. You can identify the subcode easily because the MSB is set to one in all bytes, which is the case at the start of each track on a CD.

I didn't succeed in finding a documentation about the exact meaning of the C2 error information returned by this control code. But because it has just enough room to hold one bit for each byte of the raw sector, my guess is that each bit indicates whether the corresponding byte may still contain an error after C2 error correction. Whether this assumption still holds if only the user data of a data track is returned is unknown to me. Not to mention that the information is quite meaningless because the user data returned by the function should already be corrected by the subsequent P- and Q-parity, even though it may have contained C2 errors initially.

The behavior of other track modes when trying to read mode-1 data is as follows:

- `YellowMode2` and `XAForm2` will fail.
- `RawWithC2` and `RawWithSubCode` will behave similar to `RawWithC2AndSubCode`.
- `CDDA` will yield garbled data.

Also, note that your `printf` format pattern only prints one digit for each char if its value is below `0x10`. If you wanted to always print 2 digits, `"%02hhX"` would be appropriate.